# Time no longer passes except near intelligent creatures, how does the world continue?

Tags: society, government, post-apocalypse, time

Time stops nearly everywhere, time only continues in a area around creatures of a certain intelligence. The worlds population is suddenly thrown into darkness as time ceases throughout the universe except near them, since light is no longer reaching them from outside their time bubble. They also find all electricity cuts out if the power source is outside their time field. Some people suffocate because they stay in one place to long, exhausting the air in their bubble. People can no longer rely on the sun for agriculture. Starvation is a serious threat, but so is asphyxiation.

**It is probably a given that possibly the majority of the worlds population will die**. I am wondering whether it is possible for humanity to survive in the long term, and what civilization the remnants of humanity could create. I'm not quite sure what is going to happen with all those animals that are smart enough to create time bubbles in the wild and I don't know how much that affects things. It does occur to me that the intelligent animals might not die off for quite a while as they would migrate to find new food. Although one thing to be considered is that I don't think there are any animals that are well adapted for total darkness that also pass the mirror test, so actually the animals that would generate time bubbles might die off quite quickly.

As for what methods humanity would employ to survive, and I suppose any permanent settlements would probably need CO2 scrubbers. People could move around nomadically since **time doesn't pass outside time bubbles** so if no-one has been somewhere since time stopped it will be exactly as it was at that second.

**The only places time continues are around creatures that have incredibly high intelligence** including great apes plus some other primates, cetaceans, many corvidae, elephants, parrots, pigs and a few other mammals and birds. A creature can only make time pass near itself if it individually meets the required intelligence bar, as thus human infants wont make time pass in their presence until they could pass the mirror test, this usually occurs at around 18 months.

**The time field around a creature**, in which time passes extends from every part of their body a distance equal to twice the distance between the furthest 2 points of that organisms body, this only counts living tissue (so not hair) that is a part of its body. This distance obviously changes: for instance if a person simply held up their arm then the distance between the furthest 2 points of their body increased: from being from their foot to their scalp, to being from their foot to their hand.

As for what happens to object partly on one side of the literal temporal barrier and partly on the other side (assuming the barrier either has no width or is only a planck length thick), I'm assuming through hand-waving that things straddling the temporal line aren't just cut in half and are still sort of attached to the portion on the other side should you pull on it.

**EDIT** A object can't be passed through a stationary time barrier. Once a object reached the edge and a tiny part of it has crossed the barrier it would be unable to move and would block the rest of the object from getting through. A object part outside the barrier and part inside could not be pulled inside either because the part of the object outside the barrier can't move but is still attached to the part inside the barrier. A object normally wouldn't be able to touch the edge of a stationary time barrier anyway because there will be a layer of air molecules trapped partly on both sides of the barrier. Pulling a object that is partly outside the barrier could be done but you would be breaking the object by pulling it hard enough to rip it apart.

In this scenario everything still has a gravitational pull on everything else but objects outside time bubbles just don't react since that would require time. In addition I'm assuming that since from the perspective of people in time bubbles the earth is no longer moving that people don't just get flung at deadly speed as this would kill everyone in fractions of a second. **In this scenario I'm assuming that anything that would kill everyone within a incredibly short time is somehow resolved**, so this situation isn't enormously dull.

In terms of intelligence of a certain level being needed to make a time bubble, I am assuming that brain damage or certain mental disorders emerging may cause a creature to stop creating a time bubble but that these need to be reflected by neurological changes to have a effect, thus a creature that is unconscious or drugged will still generate a bubble.

**Ok regarding heat buildup**. I do definitely think now that heat buildup is one of the biggest problems in this scenario. I think the way the bubbles edge would handle heat is like this: there is a nearly indestructible layer of air straddling the plank-length edge of the bubble however even with a creature holding perfectly still the bubbles edge will move by molecules at a time because no creature could truly hold totally still. Most heat would indeed build up because it had no-where to go, there would only be one way that heat escapes and that would be through light mostly infrared. Light emitted within the bubble will hit the edge unlike solid object that would be held back by the layer of trapped air molecules, even if the edge of the bubble moved the light would just resume its movement away from the bubble hitting the edge again. Thus light would be basically the only way heat would escape the mostly closed system of the bubble.

Comment: I tried to make it clear in one of the bolded texts that time really doesn't pass outside time bubbles, this means areas no highly intelligent creatures have been to since time stopped are still perfectly preserved. So air wouldn't run out everywhere. The more pressing issue is that if you were ~6 ft tall the amount of plants needed to feed you (which is also the exact amount needed to produce enough oxygen for you), probably couldn't be grown in in your small time field which only extends ~12 ft from you

Comment: I do believe your comment has answered your question.

Comment: I was just clarifying the things one person didn't seem to understand in the questions sandbox

Comment: My question is about what people would do once this event occurred the question and my comment is purely about what this effect does and some of the no-brainer results of the event.

Comment: With no light/heat reaching you from outside of the bubble, you'd probably freeze to death.

Comment: but the heat already in the bubble can't radiate out so I would expect it to maintain equilibrium

Comment: How do overlapping time bubbles work? Is it just redundant, or does the area grow outwards?

Comment: What counts as my body? If I get a skin graft that's still attached to 200 meters of growing skin in a nutrient bath does that count as a point on my body? If people hold hands does the bubble around them grow to treat them as one? Also I'm almost certain that there's some hack involving interlocking bubbles that could be used to make an infinitely strong fusion chamber with walls made out of areas of stopped time.

Comment: overlapping time bubbles are redundant, you can get skin grafts or something like that to make your time bubble bigger but any grafted on material must have your genetic makeup and be alive and connected to the rest of your body (bloodflow to the grafted on part etc).

Comment: It should obviously be noted that although extending the size of a bubble by using skin grafts from your own body would be somewhat necessary to to survive doing that kind of thing requires medical expertise.

Comment: Given that all other issues are resolved..we all still die...people may survive for a while by wandering and foraging for food, but it takes approximately 1.2 acres of farmland to feed a single human being...so yeah if food isn't growing we die.

Comment: Yes people will all die if they can't solve the engineering problems, but if nearly everybody dies right away then the remaining people have a lot of paused land they can gather food from before they exhaust everywhere on earth they can get to.

Comment: Be nice if you could "accept" one of the answers, or renew interest by editing and/or making a bounty.  I still think it's one of the most original ideas I've seen in a while.

Comment: @JDługosz Yeah I might consider putting a bounty on this question, but I'd want to put this question through a series of edits first. It's one of my earliest questions and is somewhat poorly written.

Comment: Looking forward to it.  Depending on what you want to explore, you might either edit or post a new question referring back to this one (or both).  Spinoff questions can be much more narrowly focused on some aspect of a Universe explored in an older question.

Comment: @JDługosz Yeah but before I work on this question I will probably make 1 or 2 other questions first that I've been planning to do.

Comment: This is basically just every open-world video game ever.  All the NPCs and monsters basically just sit around waiting for players to come and interact with them.

Comment: Spend some time on a Minecraft server, its a similar experience. Chunks load when a player is in them, meaning crops in a far distant field wont grow and distant villages wont be raided by zombies etc.

Comment: BTW you still never Accepted an answer or started that bounty (see earlier comments).

Comment: @StephenDiMarco beat me to it, but I'll add to what Stephen started. What is described is similar to a Minecraft world, and in the game of Minecraft the world needs time for players to survive. In order to stay alive you need to eat, to eat you usually grow crops or raise livestock. In-game, when you go out for an adventure to faraway lands, you might come back to a farm where your plants have not grown in your absence because no time passed, yet you are now starving. One exception: The area surrounding your initial spawn-point where you entered the world always has time pass for it.

Answer (score 21):

I had a thought concerning this idea. BTW, congratulations for the originality. It piqued my interest for that reason alone.

### The World *is* a Simulation

Normally, physics is computed/rendered “as needed”, with shortcuts taken where possible. Intelligent minds, in particular, are the driving point and are always rendered in full detail with very fine time steps. Things in the immediate environment need to be driven to sufficiently high resolution, too. But if you look at a pool of water that has been unobserved for some time,

① it jumps ahead without realizing states in between. (See Greg Egan’s  short story *Dust* that became expanded into [*Permutation City*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_City).)
② entropy and information content is used to deliver only what’s needed. There is no need to get every molecule of water in its exact position; an indistinguishable lot and bulk properties is all that’s needed.

Now the simulation has been running out of resources. More people. More detailed observation of the world, from close-up views of astronomical phenomena to atomic resolution microscopes. High-tech devices require constant reliance on high-detail quantum mechanics of small groups of atoms, *en masse*.

What happens when servers are stressed? Timing issues, swapfile and caching issues, random memory writes more likely to hit something meaningful… however our universe is implemented, it is an information system and will have analogous issues.

### Cue the bugs.

Unobserved areas are not computed until needed, and then mechanisms are invoked to decide whether to catch-up in one (or a few coarse) gulps, how to simplify re entropy, etc. (Think of lazy evaluation in [Haskel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)).)

**That stops working.** The stuff you look at causes crashes/exceptions/corruption, and the state is *not caught up*. It shows the same state that existed the last time it was observed, unchanged.

This gives you lots of latitude to adjust the effects and naturally give inconsistent results, especially to (somehow) get stuff to work out.

It also allows you to have the effects *progress* over time. Anomalies become full scale missing time in astronomical observations and quantum system experiments.  Wilderness disappears but  (remote) servers still work. Then eventually advanced semiconductors only work when being operated directly and in close proximity, and finally the bubbles close in around people individually.

In this scheme, it is natural that the bubbles won’t be black, but you will see the frozen reality beyond. The sun shines on people.

### Story plot and Framework

The breakdown of the simulation and discovery of the true nature can be a major thread in the story. It can also give access to a study of “meta physics” and even *exploits* to hack into it.

The malfunctioning simulation hypothesis natually lets you tune the details how you like even to the point of inconsistent rules or changing phenomena.  Just add special cases and glitches: rather than plot holes, they provide insight into the underlying code and clues for crafting intentional exploits!

Personally,  I would love to read that novel.

Comment: I like this explanation because a version of this could explain the world I described quite well and it gives it an explanation, I still think if the simulation was actually simulating all the particles on the atomic scale it would work with my description of the bubble as black.

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain? If it contains inaccuracies, problems, or misses the point, it needs a comment to indicate *what*. This seems to be a high-quality answer that's endorced as being to-to-pointnby the OP, so I hace to wonder, do you know the purpose of downvoting on SE? Is this some kind od "personal" issue?

Comment: The only reason I can think of for the downvoting, is that you proposed a interesting explanation, but the question was more about what society would do, and also indirectly about how to solve many of the engineering problems created by this scenario.

Comment: I suppose the question was downvoted by (same?) someone because it's not clear what the question is.  Outside of the Title line, there is no question, just presentation of a scenario.  But I thought "cool, I'll think about that too" rather than flagging it. On a more typical SE it would have been closed (most downvoters/flaggers don't consider the Title as part of the question, it seems in my experience).

Comment: Upvoted because this seems to be the only way to make this premise into a story without handwaving everything away. And I like it!

Comment: The simulation hypothesis (one which relies on simplifications, adaptive mesh refinement, etc) is very claustrophobic: The universe may not be much bigger than it's own people (including alien minds). The cost of 8 billion brains could well exceed everything else in the solar system and all computers on Earth. A single Dyson sphere even 1% completed would run the servers to the ground when use it's energy to power ultracomputers and virtual minds. Lets hope we are not in a simulation!

Comment: Would it frank crash the computer or would the computer be forced to throttle like a weak Minecraft server where it lags and glitches out of necessity rather than an actual "bug"? Meaning the algorithm is doing the best it can but it only has so much memory.

Answer (score 7):

Regardless of the availability of CO₂ scrubbers (and in the long run I suspect you are greatly overestimating what can be done along those lines, especially with no prior warning), it seems clear that most people will be dead within 24 hours, 48 at most. The problem is not CO₂ , it's heat. Not only is the world outside the bubble perfectly black, the surface of the bubble is a perfect insulator. Thermal vibrations cannot propagate outside the bubble, nor can IR radiation.

Nominal Basal Metabolic Rate for a resting, 100 kg, 25-year-old male is 2,000 kcal/day, or about 8 MJ/day. During an eight-hour sleep cycle that will be 2.7 MJ. Within a personal bubble, all of the heat must be absorbed by the sleeper, for a total thermal load of 27 kJ/kg. Since the specific heat of water is about 4000 J/kg-C, at the end of eight hours your body temperature will be about 110 degrees, which is hardly survivable. Sweating won't help much. At 30°C the density of saturated water vapor is about 30g/cu meter. For a 2-meter radius bubble, that's about .36 kg. Using 2.2 kJ/g as heat of vaporization, evaporation can mitigate about 800 kJ of metabolic energy, so the actual rise will be on the order of 8 degrees, for a waking fever of about 107 °F.

Smaller individuals, of course, will generate less heat, but they have less mass to heat up.

The idea of using generators for farming and running CO₂ scrubbers consequently becomes disastrous. A 10 kW generator will produce 860 MJ of energy per day, and virtually all of this will end up as heat in a bubble. Regardless of bubble size, the specific heat of air is quite small, so most of the heat will go to warming up the generator, animals and people. Not to mention that the air will quickly become saturated with water vapor from the generator exhaust. Water vapor is not usually considered, but it is a major component of hydrocarbon combustion. Dehumdifiers don't actually help much, since they require large amounts of energy to cool the water vapor in the air for condensation. And if, somehow, the people survive long enough to actually start eating the farm's food, all the energy which went into producing food value will be released as heat as the food is metabolized.

Oh yes, and pigs will be particularly hard hit. They don't sweat.

---

EDIT — Addressing the possibility that heat hits the shell of the bubble and is trapped there. Fine. We can do this two ways.

First, let's take it literally. Then the shell will trap ALL thermal energy impinging on it, and will act like a surface of infinite thermal conductivity with a surface temperature of absolute zero. The inside becomes a super refrigerator, and the person freezes to death, but probably not before the air freezes out and asphyxiates him.

Alternatively, the shell maintains thermal equilibrium with the "nominal" temperature of the environment just outside. This causes it to absorb excess heat and store it in a thin layer which forms the thickness of the bubble's shell. Let's assume that the trapping layer is 10 mm thick. Consider the idea that a person has slept for 8 hours keeping perfectly still, then rolls over. During his sleep, he has emitted 2.7 MJ of energy, all of which has been trapped in the storage layer (this isn't quite true, since some of it will have been absorbed by the ground the sleeper is lying on, but let's ignore that). As the sleeper rolls over, the bubble moves with him, bringing the near side of the external environment, including the storage layer, inside the bubble.

Considering the half of the shell above ground, this will amount to 1/4 of the total storage layer. This will consist of 4π × .01 meters, or .12 cu meters. This weighs about .14 kg. During the night, this accumulated 2.7 MJ / 4, or about 600 kJ. The specific heat of air is just about 1 kJ/kg-C, so this air will be effectively heated to 600 / .14, or 4300 degrees Centigrade. This will instantly raise the internal temperature by 40 degrees C, and the pressure by nearly 2 psi. The sleeper will possibly be woken up when his eardrums rupture.

Comment: Aren't there generators which take away heat to provide another form of energy? Maybe if people spread out to cover as much area with time-bubbles as they can we can get enough generators working, along with other necessary things. But the coordination that would require is probably unrealistic.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, isn't the heat still lost? It would attempt to travel outside your bubble, but then just stops moving - its not like it is reflected and held inside the bubble.

Comment: "Aren't there generators which take away heat to provide another form of energy?" No. Heat is the end result of any other forms of energy interacting with the universe.  One version of the First Law of Thermodynamics: "Work is heat and heat is work." And "if people spread out ... we can get enough generators working" suggests that you have entirely missed the point.

Comment: My reasoning with "if people spread out" is that it introduces more and more objects to absorb the heat - which may slow the heat death down somewhat, until a solution is found - if possible.

Comment: "its not like it is reflected and held inside the bubble" - Oh yes it is.  Or, let's put it this way - if heat did somehow "collect" on the inside of the bubble, the edge of the bubble would become a thin zone of extremely high temperature, and would fry anybody who tried to enter the bubble, or would be released the instant the occupant moves.

Comment: It would probably be best if you could continually keep moving in a duo then - so it didn't build up. As a duo you could take turns sleeping. Moving would bring you in contact with new oxygen and leave CO2 and heat behind. But you would still come across areas that maybe others had built up a bunch of heat in or used up all the oxygen. Eventually if these don't get restored everyone dies but the last survivors may be around for quite a while.

Comment: I think given the problems with heat buildup it might be advantageous to start out in a cold area so when you move around to mix the air from one bubble with another you don't have to try as hard since the outside air is really cold even if the inside air is to hot. Another way I considered getting cold fresh air would be attaching a lightweight animal like a magpie to a weather balloon, possibly wrapping it in insulating cloth and giving it a small oxygen mask, then moving the weather balloon on a rope up and down mixing cold high altitude air with the hot air of the bubble on the ground.

Comment: No, that won't work. The problem is that air takes almost no energy to heat, compared with what it takes to heat a human body (a bag of water, essentially). With a specific heat of 1 kJ/kg, heating a bubble's worth of air an extra 50 C (80 F) will only take 7 kJ out of (more or less) 2700 kJ. Less than 1%. Please try to keep up with the math. I'm going through the steps so you can do this sort of thing on your own.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Ok not sure if you are replying to me, but if so I'm not sure why regularly mixing the hot air in the permanent bubbles with outside air wouldn't work, especially if you were able to have a huge amount of vertical space in which to mix it with. Another probably less effective method to cool a stationary bubble might be to try to somehow lose more heat energy through light than normal since light is the only way heat is going to leave the system normally. If all that fails you may have to build a indoor farm, generator, etc on a vehicle so you can move around nomadically.

Comment: @VakusDrake - yes I was replying to you. I'm just having a bit of difficulty figuring out where you will find a magpie (since outside any bubble is pitch black), where you will find oxygen tanks (same problem) and why I should take the idea of an oxygen mask for a magpie seriously. Then there's "you may have to build a indoor farm, generator, etc on a vehicle so you can move around nomadically". Do you have any idea how much farm area you need, or the size of vehicle (which would have to be built) to move it? Until you run the numbers, your ideas are, well, they're not what I'd call serious.

Comment: While I hardly know exactly what what the numbers involved would be, magpies are fairly common and in some areas since they are one of the few animals that generate time fields it seems inevitable that people will run into them and of course some people will hang onto any magpies they find because of their potential utility. Many of the prerequisites like indoor farms and generators already exist thus when the event hits some people will try to find them if they already know where they are same thing goes for oxygen tanks, people with access to them will understand their value.

Answer (score 4):

OK. After some brief consideration I've come up with a couple of scenarios:

1: Everybody dies.
2: Everybody dies.

It's basically a matter of degrees between the various deaths.

Let's address the basic problem here. In your answer you've expressly said that gravity still works. Sadly, without time, the same can't really be said of the other forces. That's not an issue for anything outside of the time bubble though, as they're outside time. Not is it a problem inside the bubble, where things are still normal. The problem arises at the boundary.

You've addressed some boundary conditions in your question, notably that an object (which I'm going to assume means some form of logical unit that's utterly handwaved) can still be pulled through the boundary. It's good you defined this, otherwise the lack of nuclear forces would mean that the floor would fall into itself, becoming degenerate at the bubble wall. When the person causing the bubble also started to fall the degenerate matter would either undergo nuclear fusion or just run flat into some good old chemical processes. Either way: The floor is made of lava. Everybody dies.

But you sidestepped that issue. The floor is safe!

### EDIT:

OK. Assuming that the boundary is perfectly sticky and that object can't get through the boundary, any living but unintelligent creatures on the boundary die. If you enter a new area with a colony of gerbils in it, they're all going to die from massive cellular trauma as they pass the boundary, due to the chemical reactions that let life work literally being cut in half (not to mention bloodflow, nervous and digestive issues caused by the boundary).

Secondly, there are all manner of problems with airflow. I'm not going to delve into heat retention as it's been covered in excruciatingly warm detail since my original answer, but air is still an issue.

As the OP noted, the atmosphere will rapidly stick to the walls of the bubble and become a solid 'shell' of sorts, preventing anything inside the bubble from running into the wall and causing itself trouble. I'm going to have to assume that 'stuck' here means that the probability distribution of a particle's position is centred on a point on the shell of the bubble. From the point of view of the air, this means that more and more air particles are going to be able to 'stick' to the boundary every second, and as these particles are stuck they aren't going to be able to bounce back like normal.

If the shell is completely immobile then eventually this forms a completely solid shell of particles. If not then two interesting scenarios arise:

1: A person moves steadily in a direction.

Here the problem becomes one of sheer numbers. The number of new air particles entering the shell will be lower than the number of particles sticking to the opposite side of the shell. The air pressure will decrease. The faster you move, the less this will affect you, but the effect will still be there. Sooner or later the ambient pressure is going to be low enough that you can't breathe, at which point you die. Strangely the same issue doesn't apply to sea creatures or amphibians, as water is incompressible the amount of particles stuck at the boundary is going to equal the number of particles entering.

2: The person stays as still as they can.

If you stay still then you'll only lose a little air. As you shift about, shiver in the darkness or breathe the bubble is going to move back and forth, allowing the previously stuck air to recycle into the bubble. The 'shell' of stuck particles will move outwards a little further in this case, and become a little thicker as you shift backwards and forwards, but unless you're pacing back and forth by the radius of the sphere you won't be able to exhaust all of your atmosphere. Instead you simply succumb to atmospheric degradation and die.

### EDIT:

OK. Sociological solutions without everybody dying!

As previously mentioned: large animals that can pass the mirror test are going to be immensely valuable. An elephant, though expensive in terms of food, will provide a large bubble capable of supporting multiple people.

In terms of humans: the first priority will be actually working out what's going on. Remember: Everyone has just been plunged into blackness. The walls of the bubble are going to have an albedo of 0 unless you're moving forwards, when they might glow a little. People who get hit by the change in the middle of the day are likely going to die very quickly, as they'll have no handy light sources. Those at night, already in the dark or blind will have a little more success (though still a lot of everybody dying). Finding another human being in the dark when you have no way to find them (no visual LOS, no auditory clues, no vibrations ets) is going to be hard.

For small groups of people with some form of light I think that the first few days will be survivable. As long as they keep moving they'll have air and will be able to scavenge new resources, but they'll have to watch out for other, similarly minded groups and make sure they don't get split up. Tribal nomads with  high resource contention and no way to know when another tribe is nearby sounds like a recipe for some pretty unexpected and brutal fighting.

In the end though, everyone still dies. Handwaving away temperature issues leaves us with a total lack of renewable resources. Batteries will run out. Trees and plants will not regrow. It's hard to pump diesel when time's stopped in the middle of the tank, not to mention the pollution inside the bubbles. Groups of mobile raiders will last the longest, potentially biker gangs or long distance drivers, but eventually even they are going to die in the dark.

All in all: If they don't die fast, they die brutally. Everyone dies.

Comment: Ok While a lot of the points you originally brought up are valid, I have addressed most of these issues since then. The mostly immovable barrier of air on the edge of the barrier solves a lot of problems. You don't need a elephant to make a time bubble the common Eurasian magpie and even pigs both have the necessary intelligence bar as explained in my question (though the size of the bubble is related to the size of the creature), pigs seem to be able to act upon information in mirrors, also since ants can pass the mirror test I somewhat question exactly how useful the mirror test is.

Comment: All the other points you brought up have also been addressed, and many of the questions about the viability of survival long-term in this scenario actually hinge on how feasible it is to do large dangling skin grafts, (see my answer to my question).

Comment: The elephant was more for a large, mobile time bubble. The volume enclosed by the elephant's time bubble is is going to be considerable without the need for any crazy skin grafts.

Comment: Also: your edit disallowing objects moving through the boundary means that a lot of air is going to get stuck at the boundary and left behind when a person moves. More air, in fact, than the person would gain from walking into the new space (air is sparse, the boundary is sticky). Now you have a choice between standing still and dying or moving forwards and dying...

Comment: Once a layer of air is stuck on the boundary more air can't get stuck because the air already on the planck length boundary is in the way.

Comment: Just run the numbers and it seems I've overestimated the rate of loss by quite a lot! You can stick about 0.006 of a mole of atmosphere to the wall of the sphere before you have (to all intents and purposes) a solid wall of particles. You still have the issue of not gaining this many particles when you move into a new area though, so the air pressure will steadily decrease the more you move, and the air quality will degrade if you don't...

Comment: Of course the temporal boundary would never be completely still, since peoples body would be moving slightly at any time, even if only by molecules at a time.

Answer (score 2):

**While nearly everyone would die I have upon thinking about it resolved how I suspect most people would die and how some might live:**

**How most people die:** While I originally suspected people would die of asphyxiation, I don't think that's how most people outside crowded cities would die. Instead I think that people would move to avoid having their bubble run out of oxygen. However most of the easily accessible food is likely stored in areas like super markets that would run out of oxygen incredibly quickly. Once places a lot of people would go to like supermarkets run out of air, then going there would require a oxygen tank or carbon scrubber.

**Larger bubbles:** One implication of the rules I established regarding the time fields may make survival possible for a small number, skin grafts. While the procedure would require medical expertise grafting skin from say your abdomen into living strips connected to your blood supply could enlarge your bubble substantially if the strip trailed off your body.

**Large permanent time fields:** Due to the fact people wouldn't want to stand next to a generator they need to run, or stand in the middle of a super-efficient algae farm, and of course stand at intervals along the power-line from the generator to indoor farm. People would get time fields another way, animals: By taking animals intelligent enough to generate time field and grafting long strips of their own living skin onto the front and back of the animal, you can get large  time field that are necessary to run well anything.

**Long term:** While there may be many things I'm failing to take into account, I think it may be possible for groups of people to survive. Utilizing power plants and indoor farms with pigs with a long strip of their own living skin trailing as far as possible (maybe 20-100 ft?) in both direction generating the necessary time fields. In the long term large problems might be genetic diversity (though you might be able to easily make your way to perfectly preserved sperm banks), and obtaining resources, since any large scale operation would require nearby power plants to run co2 scrubbers (and lot of animals with skin grafts to generate time fields).

**Government:** While individual governments would vary I can predict with some confidence what they would find valuable:

Unlike many other post-apocalyptic scenarios canned food would be no more useful than normal food since shelf life isn't very meaningful though any food or water is useful. Gas and other fuels are useful for generators. Medical expertise is incredibly valuable for normal reasons but mostly because skin grafts are incredibly necessary. Co2 scrubbers are valuable for obvious reasons but any oxygen tanks are also quite valuable so you can scavenge for food in de-oxenagated areas.

Helium and other buoyant gasses might also be valuable for several reasons: One when outside you can attach your long skin graft to a balloon to extend your bubble size. You could also attach a light weight animal able to generate a time field (with skin grafts to maximize bubble size) to a balloon which you hold onto with a rope and move up and down to mix fresh air from just above where any bubbles have been with your time field. While air on the ground in many places would be depleted there is a huge amount of air above where most people can reach that will still be fresh.

**EDIT, Nomads:** While some people might try to survive in permanent settlements, probably more people would survive as nomads. Nomadic people would probably become very good at navigating while being limited to not seeing outside their bubble nomads would probably also use torches to see inside their bubble since plant material would be easiest to get. Nomads would use any form of ranged weapon since any wildlife you encounter unable to make its own time field can't escape you. Temporary settlements: nomads might use trained magpies attached to ropes letting them fly up vertically then come back down mingling the air of the birds fresh bubble with the old stale air. Nomads would also stick together for fear of getting separated.

Comment: You're going to make a 20'-100' skin graft, in the dark, by cutting strips of your own skin off? How do you intend to pump blood through the skin? You won't be able to keep it alive and you'll be back to square one with a good chunk of your abdomen skin missing.

Comment: That's why I said you would need medical expertise but I certainly don't think this kind of skin graft is impossible, and you would obviously have a flashlight or some other contained light source. You would need medical equipment and 1 or more doctors doing the procedure which is why most people would die.

Comment: You'd need a new heart to pump through that distance too, especially if you're using a balloon to lift it in the air. You couldn't do this in a regular world, let alone one where time has stopped and most people are dead or unable to find each other.

Comment: the strip of skin doesn't have to be very thick it only needs to be able to be kept alive connected to your body

Comment: If it's thick enough to pump blood through it, then it's thick enough to wound you significantly by removing it.

Comment: I don't think the skin would need to be any thicker than necessary to keep it alive. You wouldn't remove a 20 ft or more strip of skin from you all at once you would remove smaller strips at different time and try to connect the different skin grafts together.

Comment: While I doubt people could survive tens of thousands of years in this scenario, if they did, I can imagine they would quite rapidly evolve to consume less oxygen and also tolerate extremely high temperatures due to heat buildup inside bubbles.

Comment: I doubt a person would have time to medically graft skin to themselves/someone else before they died.

Answer (score 1):

**Everyone would die, probably via asphyxiation, while floating in the dark.**

---

It seems the only hand-waving thing you've done (aside from the obvious) is negate the conservation of momentum for the spinning Earth. That should keep everyone from getting killed *immediately*, though the future is bleak for the survivors.

### Darkness

The sunlight reaching an area would last as long as it takes for the light at the edge of a time bubble to cross its diameter. So, a few nanoseconds. Light requires time to propagate, it won't come streaming through the edge of the bubble because there is no time passing on the other side. As soon as the photons in the volume of the bubble is absorbed by one bit of matter or another, there aren't any more coming in to replace them. You can't see outside of your time bubble, the edges would be perfectly dark.

### Floating

You'll have the same issue with gravity. [Gravity propagates at the speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_gravity), if the mass disappears, so does the field. Like the photons, once your time bubble essentially makes the rest of the universe not exist, you'll no longer have gravity. Your mass can't *see* the mass of the Earth anymore, so you'll just float away from it. If you want to somehow handwave this away then feel free to ignore following sections which mention it, the overall outcome will be the same.

### Death

Ok, so, in the first few nanoseconds everyone is floating in the dark, but they don't immediately die. Hopefully they were not outside when this occurred, because they might end up getting to freeze to death or asphyxiate if they can't stop themselves from floating upward. Those people will get a little light though, as they move up more photons will be released from stasis in a column above them.

Lack of oxygen is not going to be the killer here, it will be CO₂ buildup. You probably know this since you mention C0₂ scrubbers. Without scrubbers your bubble air will kill you [in less than half a day](http://io9.com/5861679/how-long-would-you-survive-in-an-airlock). Even with scrubbers though, a time bubble will only have enough oxygen [for a little less than a day](http://www-das.uwyo.edu/%7Egeerts/cwx/notes/chap01/ox_exer.html). For this reason alone, sharing a space with someone is only going to kill you faster.

### Nomadic Survival

People should travel alone, floating around, probably indoors. Growing plants is not really an option. The best option for light would be with batteries, which won't provide enough power (or more rightly, contain enough energy) to grow any plants. Someone might think to use a generator, but they're just going to add that deadly CO₂ to their bubble faster. People would add more CO₂ to their bubble than the plants could remove, it's easier to just use up this (suddenly non-renewable) resource, because otherwise you die.

To survive the longest you have to keep moving. To see anything inside your bubble you need light. Light will only be useful inside your bubble, so hopefully you can navigate by only seeing a meter in all directions. I suspect the most resourceful person would be able to survive for a few months. The mental toll of being stuck inside a two meter wide black sphere and being short of breath every time you wake up would certainly dampen the will to survive.

Comment: According to OP, "everything still has a gravitational pull on everything else". So he's handwaving gravitational issues away.

Comment: @RobWatts You downvote for that? You should read the whole answer, clearly I know he wrote that, it's why I said "If you want to somehow handwave this away then feel free to ignore following sections which mention it, the overall outcome will be the same."

Comment: Actually, as far as I understand things, gravity does not propagate at the speed of light, only changes in gravity do. (Gravity is just there already, being a local curvature of spacetime.)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Right, changes propagate at the speed of light. Without the mass, or the energy from annihilating it, the [stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) can no longer act to curve spacetime. That change (the lack of mass or energy), will propagate at the speed of light.

Comment: If time is not passing at the event horizon of a black hole, yet it stillmhas gravity, perhaps Earth should still hold on to people.  The issue I see is with movement: e.g. how can it only be rotating near people?

Comment: @JDługosz As far as I understand it, [time *does* pass the event horizon](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48026/45770). I didn't include what might happen if the Earth were still rotating near people because the OP said "In this scenario I'm assuming that anything that would kill everyone within a incredibly short time is somehow resolved". Keeping the momentum would likely kill everyone immediately. The wall of the bubble is essentially an impenetrable stasis field, if the Earth continued its spin as time started it would slam into one side of the bubble at ~1000 mph.

Comment: The stronger the gravity,  the slower the time. If you lower a watch toward the event horizon you see it ticking slower and slower and asyemtopicly toward zero as you get closer.  So when he says "no sense in which time does not pass" that doesn't make sense. The *sense* is that events stop following each other and nothing changes.  IAC note that any light will be redshifted to infimity but gravity still *works*. The mechanism of stopping time can easily refer to this to explain why gravity still works.

Comment: @JDługosz The event horizon doesn't have infinite gravity, so how can you say that there is no passage of time at the event horizon? Infinitesimally small is *not* the same as zero. So, time slows as gravity increases, how do you then infer that gravity will remain the same when time is fully stopped? I'm not seeing the logic there. It's a good thing to point to if you want to claim gravity will be infinitely strong, but not for gravity simply being unaffected.

Comment: @Samuel to reply to what you said about what what would happen if the issues with relative speed weren't resolved; the bubble moves with your body so you couldn't hit that.

Comment: @Samuel About what you said regarding freezing to death, that's a common misconception. If you're staying stationary the edge of your bubble is basically like a vacuum the only way you lose heat is through infrared radiation, which is a slow process a vacuum or the edge of your time bubble is actually a incredible insulator and the opposite problem (heat building up in the bubble) might be much more prevalent.

Comment: @VakusDrake If you're floating up through to the upper atmosphere you will [either freeze to death or asphyxiate](https://what-if.xkcd.com/64/). This is not a common misconception.

Comment: @Samuel you can't measure the time *at* the event horizon because you would have zero signal and can't read the clock. It doesn't take infinite gravity--it takes the amount that forms the event horizon. Infir: gravity isn't getting weaker and weaker approaching zero. If it did blink out suddenly, and all the mass is *beyond* that point, the BH wouldn't work.  Look up the classic Physics FAQ as there is a question concerning how gravity manages to "get out".

Comment: @Samuel I don't know why you're bringing up the upper atmosphere, the upper atmosphere is incredibly cold because the air in the upper atmosphere is cold. A vacuum doesn't have any air to transfer heat with so it doesn't really have a temperature and serves as a good insulator.                                                                                                   EDIT: I thought you meant people would freeze to death under normal circumstances, I see now that you only meant that if they weren't experiencing gravity and  floated into the upper atmosphere they would die.

Comment: @JDługosz The gravity can "get out" because time is not *stopped*.

Comment: Do you understand what I'I'm saying? All physical processes slow down to zero. Meat does not rot, gas molecules don't dispurse, muons don't decay. That is the same situation as in the story.  It's a good way to handwave the issue of gravity and sound plausible.

Comment: I disagree about the edge of the bubble insulating all the heat. If I'm an atom full of energy and bump into the edge of the bubble - I, and my energy, are now trapped outside of time and lost until the person moves me into time again. Compared to still moving, but nothing to transfer my energy too, like in a vacuum.

Comment: @DoubleDouble though that process is limited since the air already on the boundary will block any more particles from touching it.

Answer (score 0):

A very intriguing thought experiment. Star and points for that.

JDLugosz has already made some fine points about this, his main pont **the world is a simulation** makes a very good premise. Physics and events would match up to a (bad) computer game. In fact games use a LOT of these shortcuts:

- Occlusion culling: What the user cannot see, is not rendered by the game engine
- NPCs: Non-player characters are spawned into existence when and wherever they are needed. They may have some tasks running "in the background" (eg. Skyrim and newer Fallout games...) all NPCs have daily tasks, but when the user looks/walks away, their bodily "form" or "shell" is unloaded.

In this case, any animal outside the time bubble will stand (nearly) still... Intelligent or not, the given animal will be none the wiser, as it will experience the altered timeframe as you all would experience time right now.

The point is, that **time is relative**... Time also slows down for a pilot of a near-lightspeed space ship, but he still experiences that timeframe as being unaltered.

As for the humans:

**THEY WILL (nearly) ALL DIE!**

Why? Because the low-to-none amount of light (depending on time dilation factor) will make humanity unable to grow crops.

Of course, you could plant a field of wheat and walk away, but depending on the time dilation factor, it may take hundreds or thousands of years in relation to the farmer to grow the crops.

You can also go kill an animal (easy, you just extend your time field around their heart... imagine your heart beating a million beats per minute), but the animals also take hundreds or thousands of years to grow and reproduce compared to the human timeframe.
Any animal that comes into contact with or cross a time field like this, is very probably going to die immediately and painfully...

The remaining humans will not be able to eat meat (apart from very rare occasions), and they will only be limited to crops that can grow under low-light conditions (good example being mushrooms, which thrive in darkenss).
New jobs would include literally watching plants grow and paint dry, to make sure it happens this century...

Where you have to be careful, and where many go wrong, is that time outside *cannot stand perfectly still*! Space and time are two very intermingled forces, and one cannot exist without the other. This rule applies in reality, but not for a simulation (as things are dynamically loaded and unloaded as needed)

Essentially:
Time needs space so that something can happen. (without time at all, there cannot be a "big bang" or a growing universe)

on the other hand..

Space needs time to grow and change. (without space, how would you move about or do something?)