# What if our world is a program?

Tags: simulated-worlds

Like, I mean what if all of us, the fact that we exist, is nothing but an algortihm and humans, intelligent, evolving functions or objects or even classes, inheriting from one main class/template.

Edit: Sorry that i forgot to add this, but my thought was that, if it is possible that someone could find out how to manipulate this? What are the possibilities then? Will that person be god or will he just end up crashing the whole world as a whole?

Comment: Yes it is! You can do nothing about it. See: http://www.simulation-argument.com/simulation.html
... but what again is your question?

Comment: This is way broad ! Just take a look at this question: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3136/if-our-universe-was-a-simulation-what-could-a-bug-look-like. Much narrower and yet tons of answers and got closed for a while for being too broad too. This other question is also related: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/hacking-the-universe

Comment: Even the edit doesn't really change anything, but makes the question even broader.

Comment: @Aniruddh Rao Welcome to the site.  As the other comments have mentioned this question is currently to broad for us to effectively answer.  If you would like a little assistance please review the helps center for posting good questions: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help  You are also welcome to discuss the question in Chat or on the Meta board.  Again welcome to the site.

Comment: @Ghanima - links like your is exactly why I hang around this forum!

Comment: @PeterMasiar, thanks, but I just picked that one up someplace else on WB.SE ;)

Comment: Most interesting, if the world is a program, it may have bugs: specific actions under certain circumstances may result happening impossible to explain, magic - like things. And experimenting with this "magic" would be dangerous, with potential to crash the whole world!

Answer (score 1):

I like that Idea but the answer is pretty boring.

An algorithm is nothing else than a rule of execution. You can also say "Theoretical law of nature".

A simulation on other hand is the execution of an algorithm (See [tourinmachine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine)).

I assume that you are talking about a "computer-simulation" and then I state, that a computer is nothing else than an environment which is capable of execute an algorithm.

So depending on this states, our world actually is a simulation.

EDIT due to your edit:
This doesn't change anything. If one "finds out" is the same like normal science under assumtion that it is a simulation. 
And if one is able to "manipulate" it's the same as one could alter laws of nature in real world.